# Python print individual anchor text and href on individual lines

Tags: python

I have the following Python script that scrapes all anchor text and href values from a page:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/path-here"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

b  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))

for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    print (tag.text)
```

It works fine but i want it to print the anchor text (plus a dash) and the corresponding href value on the same line e.g:

```
get quote - https://www.mydomain.co.uk/get-quote
contact us - https://www.mydomain.co.uk/contact us
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the two loops:

```py
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print("%s - %s" % (link.text, link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it a bit to get it working - print(link.text, '-', link.get('href'))